# How to display handlebars variable inside html code style?

Tags: html, css, templates, handlebars.js, template-engine

I've been trying to do the following in my `.hbs` file:

```
<div class="nav-avatar" style="background-image: url('\{{ url }}avatar/\{{ user.pic }}');"></div>
```

However the CSS when looking through the website looks as so:

```
<div class="nav-avatar" style="background-image: url('avatar/');"></div>
```

Both `{{ url }}` and `{{ user.pic }}` display as they should otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I over complicated the problem. Didn't need to escape it.

```
<div class="nav-avatar" style="background-image: url('{{ url }}avatar/{{ user.pic }}');"></div>
```